# how do I remove spaces between these text boxes?

Tags: html, forms

How do I remove the spaces in this form between text boxes?

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:email@isp.com">
    <p>First name: <input name="firstname" type="text" size="15"/>Last Name:   <input name="lastname" type="text" size="20"/></p>
    <p>Address: <input name="address" type="text" size="50"/></p>
    <p>City: <input name="city" type="text" size="25"/></p>
    <p>State: <input name="state" type="text" size="5"/></p>
    <p>Zip: <input name="zip" type="text" size="10"/></p>
    <p>E-mail address: <input name="E-mail" type="text" size="30"/></p>
    <hr style="size: auto; width: auto;">
    </hr>

    <hr style="size: auto; width: auto;">
    </hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `</br>` unstead of `<p> </p>` like this:

```
Address: <input name="address" type="text" size="50"</br>
City: <input name="city" type="text" size="25"/></br>
```

But it will delete all the space.

From some website: Use the `<br>` tag to enter line breaks, not to separate paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the spaces are coming from the margins of each `<p>` tag. Removing the margins seems to work.

```
p { //You'll likely want this to be more specific, like "form p {..." or a class name
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Long and proper way

The spaces are caused by browser-defined margins that you need to reset using CSS. This is essentially working from a 'clean slate', without the browser defining default values you don't know about.

Put this inside a CSS file called 'reset.css'.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Then link it in the top of the 'head' in your html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
```

**Note:** Make sure the reset is the first stylesheet that is loaded. Otherwise everything will be reset after you've made your own adjustments.

## Short way

To solve the problem specific to this page, you must reset the margin of all `<p>` elements. In your CSS file:

```
form p {
  margin: 0;
}
```